# Pass current_user.id into actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Im trying to pass the current_employer.id into action mailer. So i cans end an email to users that belong to the Employer.

my mailer looks like this.

```
class ScheduleMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default to: Proc.new { Employee.where(:employer_id => current_employer.id
       ).pluck(:email) },
       from: 'noreply@scheduled.com'



 def schedule_post_reg(employ)

 mail( :subject => "Your schedule has been posted.")

 end


 end
```

I get this error

```
 NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_employer' for #<ScheduleMailer:0x0000010cec0880>):
  app/mailers/schedule_mailer.rb:3:in `block in <class:ScheduleMailer>'
  app/mailers/schedule_mailer.rb:10:in `schedule_post_reg'
  app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:235:in `approve_shift'
```

Any suggestion on how to pass the current_employer.id not the actionmailer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your controller   `@employer = Employer.find_by_id(user_id)
    employer = @employer
    ScheduleMailer.schedule_post_reg(employ, @employer).deliver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mailer` has no direct access to the request context. The reason is because an email is not necessarily a result of an HTTP request. If you deliver the email from the CLI, for instance, there is no HTTP request.

You need to pass the `employer` as argument of the mailer.

```
class ScheduleMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: 'noreply@usescheduled.com'

  def schedule_post_reg(employee, employ)
    mail({
      :to => employee.email
      :subject => "Your schedule has been posted.")
    })
  end

end
```

If you need to send the same email to different employees, given a single employer, you can either pass the employer and pluck all the emails into the "to:" field (but all the recipients will see all the other emails)

```
  def schedule_post_reg(employer, employ)
    mail({
      :to => Employee.where(:employer_id => employer.id).pluck(:email)
      :subject => "Your schedule has been posted.")
    })
  end
```

or use `bcc`, or loop all the emails and call the mailer once for every employee email to generate a different email for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller write somethigng like this

```
@employer = Employer.find_by_id(params[:id])
ScheduleMailer.schedule_post_reg(employ, @employer).deliver
```

In Mailer

```
def schedule_post_reg(employ, employer)
    employees_emails = Employee.where(:employer_id => employer.id
   ).map(&:email).join(",")
    mail(:to => employees_emails, :subject => "Your schedule has been posted.")
end
```